# How to get the updated rowData after a cell is edited?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I have an AG grid component and set the useState on the rowData but after implementing a useEffect to get whether edit side effects are caught, they aren't. Is there an easy way to get the updated rowData after an AG grid edit?

For example:

```
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
import React, { useMemo, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';

const MyComponent = (props) => {
   const gridRef = useRef(null);

   const [rowData, setRowData] = useState(props.initialRowData);

   useEffect(() => { 
      console.log(rowData); // <<< always same as props.initialRowData though an edit happened
   , [rowData]};

   <div className="grid ag-theme-alpine">
        <AgGridReact
          ref={gridRef}
          rowData={rowData}
          columnDefs={props.columnDefs}
        />
      </div>   
};

export default MirrorGridComponent;
```

Comment: I encountered the same problem and it has not been solved yet

Answer (score 1):

you should use `useState` function to change the row data, just use `setRowData` to set new data or if you want to change the data somewhere else you should pass that state as **props** and put it inside the `useEffect` list like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setRowData(state)
}, [state])
```